# Linear Algebra: Find the matrix of L with respect to Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I am confused about L(u3) in this question.

Basis B = {u1=[1,1,1],u2=[1,1,0],u3=[1,0,0]}
Let L(c1u1+c2u2+c3u3)=(c1+c2+c3)u1+(2c1+c3)u2-(2c2+c3)u3

Find the matrix of L with respect to B

L(u1)=L(1u1+0u2+0u3)= [1,2,0]

L(u2)=L(0u1+1u2+0u3)= [1,0,-2]

L(u3)=L(0u1+0u2+0u3)= [1,1,0]

This is all work that is given to me but shouldn't L(u3)=[1,1,-1]? I get L(u1) and L(u2) but L(u3) makes no sense. I get how the first two values are 1 but why is the third value in vector 0?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't understand $L(u_1)$ too, why is the RHS not

$$\begin{align*}
L(1u_1 + 0u_2 + 0u_3) &= (1+0+0)u_1 + (2\cdot 1+0)u_2 - (2\cdot 0+0)u_3\\
&= [1,1,1] + 2[1,1,0] - 0u_3\\
&= [3,3,1] \quad\text{?}
\end{align*}$$